# Spring boot project closing immediately after started

Tags: spring-boot

I have two modules under one project like, core-project(module1,module2). module2 is spring boot module, uses service classes of module1 and includes a scheduled job in itself.

> module1 packages -> x.y.z.core.{dao,service}
>
> module2 packages -> x.y.z.app.{config, schedule}

If i did not add "scanBasePackages" annotation parameter, application fails at starting since it can not find service class in module1. If i add "scanBasePackages=z" annotation parameter, application starts successfully but it shutdowns immediately after without any proper debug/info/error log. I suspect that it can not find scheduled components under schedule package.

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Show your configuration code.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic, what do you mean by configuration code? be clear.

Comment: You mentioned `scanBasePackages` which implies you mean the annotation `SpringBootApplication`. So I mean your spring configuration. If your question would be clear I wouldnt have asked...

Comment: @mrkernelpanic you are still not clear. there are just annotations like component, service, Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000), but not any xml configuration or specific configuration class in config package, just schedule threads naming. Scheduling and application works when i clear dependencies to module1. thank you for your help!